# Wrong HttpContext in Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

We use a custom Policy to check some database requirement (a token persisted in database), and I need session informations so I injected IHttpContextAccessor to use HttpContext.Session.

```
public TokenValidHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{
     _httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
}
```

I can see that :

1. I don't retrieve correctly HttpContext.Session, it throw an InvalidOperationException
2. The request is not correct : the Path is null, and this should be something like '/Home/Index'

I re-used SessionMiddleware in my project and I can see that user session is correctly restored into the HttpContext, but in my Policy I'd get the wrong one. SessionMiddleware is correctly added before MVC Middleware. Any ideas ?

**SOLUTION** (thanks @JoeAudette)
Keep accessor until you need HttpContext.

```
public TokenValidHandler(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{            
    _accessor = contextAccessor;
}

protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, TokenValidRequirement requirement)
{
    // Right context ...
    var contextHttp = _accessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Comment: instead of getting the context in the constructor, try keep the contextAccessor around and wait to get the actual context until just before you need to check it

Comment: That was the solution :) Many hours just for this ... Maybe you can post a response so I can mark it as resolve

Comment: glad that worked, I have posted it as an answer

Comment: Ideally, you'd likely want to rework your filter as an authentication middleware and use the new claims-based authorization block, that doesn't require implementing custom code.

Comment: @Pinpoint I use Policy for specific authentication action and claims-based authorization, have you an exemple of what you'd said ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of getting the context in the constructor, try keeping the contextAccessor around and wait to get the actual context until just before you need to check it